# Set top boxes - database of ‘tv programme/channel’

Tags: data

I am currently researching the construction and functionality of set top boxes for services such as Sky + and Freeview.

I need to understand if and how a database structure would be used in terms of the operation of such hardware.

As these devices are accessing libraries of ‘tv programme/channel’ data I can only imagine that a database must form part of the set up, not least to query to achieve an on screen result.

I cannot find anything in these box technical specification to suggest that though. I have found out a little about IMDs, In-memory databases but I don’t really understanding the workings of these - can anyone help?

Comment: This isn't a real electronics question. [in-memory database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database)

Comment: Sky and Freeview adhere to the DVB standard. You want to read ETSI EN 300 468 and learn about decoding SI tables to construct an EPG. http://tsfriend.googlecode.com/files/DVB%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF.pdf

Comment: @TobyJaffey - why not make that excellent information an answer. If they migrate it the answer goes with it. If they close it the answer is still useful. If it stays as a questsion then that may be the best answer going.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Done, I just figured it was going to get closed pretty quickly

Comment: This has the phrasing of a homework question.

Comment: @Russell - I had a discussion about a similar thing with Kortuk. I understand your reasoning about migrating. But if the question is just closed because off-topic, we have ans answer which is off-topic as well. It may be useful, but so may a recipe for Brussels sprouts be, as I also said to Kortuk. I think off-topic questions shouldn't get answers.

Comment: @stevenvh - to each his own. I consider answers like that a valuable resource for people designing overall systems. Some won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sky and Freeview adhere to the DVB standard. You want to read [ETSI EN 300 468](http://tsfriend.googlecode.com/files/DVB%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF.pdf) and learn about decoding SI tables to construct an EPG.